# OpenRewrite: Do we have recipes available for .Docker File change?If not then what approach we should follow to change Docker file through OpenRewrite

Tags: openrewrite

docker file update through openrewrite if possible.

I am willing to to update Java version in docker file through OpenRewrite.

```
**FROM amazoncorretto:17**
USER root
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum upgrade -y
RUN yum update -
------
-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that plain text recipes is the best we can do here, until we get a dedicated parser for Docker. You could try if the find and replace one fits your use case: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/text/findandreplace

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).